# Bigcommerce - Is there a way to add <script> code to every page programatically?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am developing new app for Bigcommerce and I need to add script tag to every page in the shop.

Is there any way to do that progragrammatically?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a nice way but you can append and prepend php files via .htaccess after that you could modify the output via php script.
Depending on the framework an how you get access to the output.

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/test.php"
php_value auto_append_file "/dir/path/test.php"
```

Comment: Sorry Hayo that I do not write about it more clearly but it's Bigcommerce releted question. Ownej of the shop do not have access to htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a template file for the  or anything that each file uses, then you can add it there. Otherwise you might be able to write a script to do that for you, but it's probably not worth your time.

Comment: Again, it's on Bigcommerce platform

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add code in **footer.html** and it will reflect on every page.

You can find this **footer.html** file in **template/panels/**

Footer.html call in whole BC site so you can add your code here.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already mention it that I need to do that progragrammatically. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your question in detail?

Comment: If you done that and you have solution than you have to give your solution here so other people can use that. Add your answer and accept it.

Comment: I already explain what I want to achieve, and do it programmatically not by hand :)